# sudo must be setuid root error already tried everything

Tags: linux, sudo

I am getting following error while trying to switch to root.

```
[~]# sudo su -
sudo: must be setuid root
```

and I have confirmed the permission of sudo file set to correct

```
[~]# ls -l /usr/bin/sudo
---s--x--x 2 root root 190904 Mar 10  2014 /usr/bin/sudo*
```

also the user is already wheels group. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that the user has normal jail access

Comment: I have a same problem. Could you please explain more details?

Comment: For cPanel servers, you need to enable jail access from the cPanel.